# Exporting from MS Access to text file, database not fully loaded

Tags: ms-access

I exported MS Access (2013) databases to text files. The databases are huge, just to fully open them takes several minutes. Therefore, I opened the Access database and (to save time ...) before it was fully loaded into memory (i.e. at the bottom of the Access table the number of records was not displayed yet...), I immediately clicked on 'External Data'/'Text File'/etc, i.e. started the exporting process.

My co-author suggested that by not waiting for the file to be fully loaded into memory, I may end up with not all data being read into the text files or maybe they're read in the wrong way. Could this really happen, should I worry? PS: I did simple checks: calculated averages of a few columns in the MS Access database and in the resulting text (ultimately Stata) files and they don't show discrepancies, suggesting the export went all fine.

Many thanks!!! aron

Answer (score 0):

Access never loads all of a database into memory. What you see is a background process which counts the number of records to give you an indication of the size of the table opened.

So dont't worry, if your averages are good, you should have all the file there.